# No shadows or lights in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there!

I'm having trouble setting up a light in Gazebo. I tried with sunlight, directional light and spot light, and the results of each of those are quite similar, something like this.

[image: image description]

I don't know what am I doing wrong, but I tried on another computer with the same settings and they work properly.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with ROS Kinetic

Greetings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21130/no-shadows-or-lights-in-gazebo/) by [RandC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7312/randc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-11-20

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've seen this happening with every graphics card except nvidia.

---

Originally posted by [windblow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7591/windblow/) with karma: 11 on 2018-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on 2019-02-25**:
You are right. I wonder why this error still happens and it has been lasted half a year.

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on 2019-02-26**:
Could you tell me if you have fixed it out  on an Intel GPU's PC?

**Comment by [windblow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7591/windblow/) on 2019-05-03**:
I have same issue with AMD GPU and **gazebo 9.x**, so it's still here.

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-05-08**:
Are there any errors reported in ~/.gazebo/ogre.log ?

**Comment by [windblow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7591/windblow/) on 2019-05-14**:
No errors, log is mostly the same as nvidia one.

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6355/mogumbo/) on 2019-05-16**:
I can't duplicate the problem here. I got my employer to give me sudo for switching graphics adapters so I was able to try my laptop's Intel graphics. A basic gazebo .world with a "sun" light works for me on Intel. I'm using Gazebo 9.8.0-1~bionic on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Comment by [windblow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7591/windblow/) on 2019-08-20**:
Can you check Device Name in your ogre.log? Still have no success on multiple Intel/AMD machines.

**Comment by [windblow](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7591/windblow/) on 2019-08-20**:
Here's the same issue on bitbucket. Maybe if it gets more votes we would manage to draw some attention to the problem.
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2623/no-shadows-and-sun-light-with-non-nvidia

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have an onboard Intel GPU and have the same problem. Like Louise above suggested I run the `setup.sh` for Gazebo and have the `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`, `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` and `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` set. I also tried to compile Gazebo (but not all the dependencies) which did not change the rendering. Still some models are so dark that their details are not visible.

My workaround was to click on the `World` tab, then on `Scene` and finally deactivate `shadows`. If `shadows` is already deactivated, then toggle it.

[An issue](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2623) is still open on the repo.

---

Here are other related questions with the hope that the users would arrive on this page:

- https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/22442/gazebo-environment-suddenly-dark/
- https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/26737/why-does-my-gazebo-window-look-dark/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/309461/no-shadows-or-lights-in-gazebo/

---

Originally posted by [leuko](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/70639/leuko/) with karma: 11 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1